# constraint layout, centre when width is more than the max width

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

i have two text views. It has fixed margin on both sides. The text should be left aligned but on large devices with width > max width mentioned, the textview should be centered than left aligned. I am not able to get this centering on large devices.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="@{title}"
        android:textColor="?colorShade1"
        android:textSize="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/subTitle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guidelineEnd"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineStart"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="1280dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        tools:text="Title" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/subTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@{subTitle}"
        android:textColor="?colorShade1"
        android:textSize="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineEnd"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="640dp"
        tools:text="SubTitleView" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="64dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineEnd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="64dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want or what the problem is exactly. Can you post some visual guidance?

Answer (score 0):

Use `app:layout_constraintWidth_max`

This will center the LinearLayout in the constraint layout, keeping a 40dp horizontal margin until it hits 414dp width:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_max="414dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a copy of your layout in the res/layout-large folder with the second layout that will be specific for large screens.

See more in: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html
In Aliases